# Меняющаяся разметка в css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Почему при копировании CSS кода из одного файла и его вставке в другой CSS файл разметка выглядит по-другому?
Я разметил каркас, который нужен мне в одном файле и хотел его размножить, но при копировании оказалось, что на последующих копиях разметка всегда сбивается.

Comment: Приведите кусок `css` кода, который меняется при перемещении в файл, и код подключения  `css`

Answer (score 0):

Всё это зависит от редактора который вы используете.Например при копировании текста с сайта в контакте в текстовый редактор sublime text 3 может изменится не только  разметка, а также и сам шрифт.Каждый редактор по своему преобразует текст.